# What is the idiomatic way to handle shortcut of an argument in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I am writing a script that accepts arguments determining further execution. The arguments are meant to be whole words (`script.sh guess`), and their shortcuts (`script.sh g`).
The commented line is the first way I found, and the second `if` is *my* more flexible take on it. Anyway, I'm interested to hear opinions from the experienced folk.

Also, I'm wondering. Is there a way to built the regex so that it would only take either `g` or `guess`, not parts like `gue` and so on?

```
#if [[ $1 == guess || $1 == g ]]; then 
if [[ $1 =~ [guess] ]]; then
    printf "You won!"
else
    printf "You lost!"
fi
```

What is your preferred approach? I can't seem to find the right terms for the big G to find the answers here.

Comment: `case "$1" in g|guess)` ? I believe `=~ [guess]`  doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right, it doesn't. It accepts any argument that includes any member of the list `[guess]`. I completely missed and haven't tested that. The `case` works as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
case $1 in
   [Gg]|[Gg]uess) printf 'You won!\n';;
    *) printf 'You lost!\n' >&2;;
esac
```

It  should match `G` or `g` and `Guess` or `guess`. although `[Gg][Uu][Ee][Ss][Ss]` can be extreme but It should work, in bash there is also `nocasematch` shell option.

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted (and better). Thanks!

Comment: Good to know, plus an added bonus that syntax is not specific to bash, it should work on POSIX shells like dash, busybox, sh and the likes. It also ran on zsh, mksh without issues.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression for what you are describing would be

```
if [[ $1 =~ g(uess)? ]]; then  # accept g or guess
```

For any prefix, it would be

```
if [[ $1 =~ g(u(e(ss?)?)?)? ]]; then
```

Comment: This actually works the intended way, unlike the list I used. Thank you.